# Checking if the Password and Username boxes are present and default text in them, using Selenium Java Testng

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Below is the code that I wrote for verifying that the username and password fields present in the login page and the default text (Username in username box and Password in password box). I have also pasted the error that I am getting while executing this test. I did look around, did find a few things but nothing fits exactly in my case.

### Update

Added the - HTML for the page as requested. I have pasted the whole but had to remove some of the HTML content due to the content limit for this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>MS - Login
</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>


<link href="/assets/libs/jquery-icheck/skins/all.css" rel="stylesheet" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/libs/jquery-icheck/skins/all.css"/>
<link href="/assets/libs/bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-tour.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/libs/bootstrap-tour/bootstrap-tour.min.css"/>
<link href="/assets/libs/rickshaw/rickshaw.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/libs/rickshaw/rickshaw.min.css"/>
<link href="/assets/libs/morrischart/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/libs/morrischart/morris.css"/>
<link href="/assets/libs/jquery-jvectormap/css/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/libs/jquery-jvectormap/css/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css"/>
<link href="/assets/libs/jquery-clock/clock.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/libs/jquery-clock/clock.css"/>
<link href="/assets/libs/bootstrap-calendar/css/bic_calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/libs/bootstrap-calendar/css/bic_calendar.css"/>
<link href="/assets/libs/sortable/sortable-theme-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/libs/sortable/sortable-theme-bootstrap.css"/>
<link href="/assets/libs/bootstrap-xeditable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/libs/bootstrap-xeditable/css/bootstrap-editable.css"/>
<link href="/assets/libs/jquery-notifyjs/styles/metro/notify-metro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/libs/jquery-notifyjs/styles/metro/notify-metro.css"/>
<link href="/assets/css/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/css/sweetalert.css"/>
<link href="/assets/css/trumbowyg/trumbowyg.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/css/trumbowyg/trumbowyg.min.css"/>
<link href="/assets/libs/bootstrap-validator/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/libs/bootstrap-validator/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/css/bootstrap-tagsinput.css"/>
<link href="/assets/libs/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/libs/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.css"/>
<link href="/assets/libs/weatherapp/weather.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/libs/weatherapp/weather.css"/>
<link href="/assets/css/flag-icon-css/flag-icon.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/css/flag-icon-css/flag-icon.min.css"/>
<link href="/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/css/style.css"/>
<link href="/assets/css/override.css" rel="stylesheet" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/css/override.css"/>
<link href="/assets/css/testme.css" rel="stylesheet" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/css/testme.css"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/img/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/img/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/img/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/img/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/assets/img/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/assets/img/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#e74c3c">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="testme">
<meta name="application-name" content="testme">
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="/assets/img/browserconfig.xml">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/img/favicon.ico" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/img/favicon.ico">
<link href="/assets/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/assets/css/style-responsive.css"/>
<script src="/assets/libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<script src="/assets/js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var timeoutDialog,mySwitch=[];</script>
<script data-pagespeed-no-defer>//<![CDATA[
(function(){function f(a,b,d){if(a.addEventListener)a.addEventListener(b,d,!1);else if(a.attachEvent)a.attachEvent("on"+b,d);else{var c=a["on"+b];a["on"+b]=function(){d.call(this);c&&c.call(this)}}};window.pagespeed=window.pagespeed||{};var g=window.pagespeed;function k(a){this.g=[];this.f=0;this.h=!1;this.j=a;this.i=null;this.l=0;this.b=!1;this.a=0}function l(a,b){var d=b.getAttribute("data-pagespeed-lazy-position");if(d)return parseInt(d,0);var d=b.offsetTop,c=b.offsetParent;c&&(d+=l(a,c));d=Math.max(d,0);b.setAttribute("data-pagespeed-lazy-position",d);return d}
function m(a,b){var d,c,e;if(!a.b&&(0==b.offsetHeight||0==b.offsetWidth))return!1;a:if(b.currentStyle)c=b.currentStyle.position;else{if(document.defaultView&&document.defaultView.getComputedStyle&&(c=document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(b,null))){c=c.getPropertyValue("position");break a}c=b.style&&b.style.position?b.style.position:""}if("relative"==c)return!0;e=0;"number"==typeof window.pageYOffset?e=window.pageYOffset:document.body&&document.body.scrollTop?e=document.body.scrollTop:document.documentElement&&
document.documentElement.scrollTop&&(e=document.documentElement.scrollTop);d=window.innerHeight||document.documentElement.clientHeight||document.body.clientHeight;c=e;e=e+d;var h=b.getBoundingClientRect();h?(e=h.top-d,c=h.bottom):(h=l(a,b),d=h+b.offsetHeight,e=h-e,c=d-c);return e<=a.f&&0<=c+a.f}
k.prototype.m=function(a){p(a);var b=this;window.setTimeout(function(){var d=a.getAttribute("data-pagespeed-lazy-src");if(d)if((b.h||m(b,a))&&-1!=a.src.indexOf(b.j)){var c=a.parentNode,e=a.nextSibling;c&&c.removeChild(a);a.c&&(a.getAttribute=a.c);a.removeAttribute("onload");a.tagName&&"IMG"==a.tagName&&g.CriticalImages&&f(a,"load",function(){g.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);b.b&&(b.a--,0==b.a&&g.CriticalImages.checkCriticalImages())});a.removeAttribute("data-pagespeed-lazy-src");a.removeAttribute("data-pagespeed-lazy-replaced-functions");
c&&c.insertBefore(a,e);if(c=a.getAttribute("data-pagespeed-lazy-srcset"))a.srcset=c,a.removeAttribute("data-pagespeed-lazy-srcset");a.src=d}else b.g.push(a)},0)};k.prototype.loadIfVisibleAndMaybeBeacon=k.prototype.m;k.prototype.s=function(){this.h=!0;q(this)};k.prototype.loadAllImages=k.prototype.s;function q(a){var b=a.g,d=b.length;a.g=[];for(var c=0;c<d;++c)a.m(b[c])}function t(a,b){return a.a?null!=a.a(b):null!=a.getAttribute(b)}
k.prototype.u=function(){for(var a=document.getElementsByTagName("img"),b=0,d;d=a[b];b++)t(d,"data-pagespeed-lazy-src")&&p(d)};k.prototype.overrideAttributeFunctions=k.prototype.u;function p(a){t(a,"data-pagespeed-lazy-replaced-functions")||(a.c=a.getAttribute,a.getAttribute=function(a){"src"==a.toLowerCase()&&t(this,"data-pagespeed-lazy-src")&&(a="data-pagespeed-lazy-src");return this.c(a)},a.setAttribute("data-pagespeed-lazy-replaced-functions","1"))}
g.o=function(a,b){function d(){if(!(c.b&&a||c.i)){var b=200;200<(new Date).getTime()-c.l&&(b=0);c.i=window.setTimeout(function(){c.l=(new Date).getTime();q(c);c.i=null},b)}}var c=new k(b);g.lazyLoadImages=c;f(window,"load",function(){c.b=!0;c.h=a;c.f=200;if(g.CriticalImages){for(var b=0,d=document.getElementsByTagName("img"),r=0,n;n=d[r];r++)-1!=n.src.indexOf(c.j)&&t(n,"data-pagespeed-lazy-src")&&b++;c.a=b;0==c.a&&g.CriticalImages.checkCriticalImages()}q(c)});0!=b.indexOf("data")&&((new Image).src=
b);f(window,"scroll",d);f(window,"resize",d)};g.lazyLoadInit=g.o;})();

pagespeed.lazyLoadInit(true, "/pagespeed_static/1.JiBnMqyl6S.gif");

//]]></script></head>
<body class="fixed-left login-page"><noscript><meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;url='testselenium.com/login?PageSpeed=noscript'" /><style><!--table,div,span,font,p{display:none} --></style><div style="display:block">Please click <a href="testselenium.com/login?PageSpeed=noscript">here</a> if you are not redirected within a few seconds.</div></noscript>
<noscript>
<div class="nojs">
<p class="alert alert-danger"><strong><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Warning:</strong> Features of testme rely on javascript. Please enable javascript from your browser preferences.</p>
</div>
</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript">var cookieEnabled=(navigator.cookieEnabled)?true:false;if(typeof navigator.cookieEnabled=="undefined"&&!cookieEnabled){document.cookie="cfstestcookie";cookieEnabled=(document.cookie.indexOf("cfstestcookie")!=-1)?true:false;}if(!cookieEnabled){document.write('<div class="nocookie"><p class="alert alert-danger"><strong><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Warning:</strong> Features of testme require cookie, we have detected that your browser <strong>does not accept</strong> cookie at this moment. You can enable cookie via your browser\'s privacy preference settings.</p></div>');}</script><div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="md-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="full-content-center">
<p class="text-center"><script data-pagespeed-no-defer>//<![CDATA[
(function(){var g=this;function h(b,d){var a=b.split("."),c=g;a[0]in c||!c.execScript||c.execScript("var "+a[0]);for(var e;a.length&&(e=a.shift());)a.length||void 0===d?c[e]?c=c[e]:c=c[e]={}:c[e]=d};function l(b){var d=b.length;if(0<d){for(var a=Array(d),c=0;c<d;c++)a[c]=b[c];return a}return[]};function m(b){var d=window;if(d.addEventListener)d.addEventListener("load",b,!1);else if(d.attachEvent)d.attachEvent("onload",b);else{var a=d.onload;d.onload=function(){b.call(this);a&&a.call(this)}}};var n;function p(b,d,a,c,e){this.h=b;this.j=d;this.l=a;this.f=e;this.g={height:window.innerHeight||document.documentElement.clientHeight||document.body.clientHeight,width:window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth||document.body.clientWidth};this.i=c;this.b={};this.a=[];this.c={}}function q(b,d){var a,c,e=d.getAttribute("data-pagespeed-url-hash");if(a=e&&!(e in b.c))if(0>=d.offsetWidth&&0>=d.offsetHeight)a=!1;else{c=d.getBoundingClientRect();var f=document.body;a=c.top+("pageYOffset"in window?window.pageYOffset:(document.documentElement||f.parentNode||f).scrollTop);c=c.left+("pageXOffset"in window?window.pageXOffset:(document.documentElement||f.parentNode||f).scrollLeft);f=a.toString()+","+c;b.b.hasOwnProperty(f)?a=!1:(b.b[f]=!0,a=a<=b.g.height&&c<=b.g.width)}a&&(b.a.push(e),b.c[e]=!0)}p.prototype.checkImageForCriticality=function(b){b.getBoundingClientRect&&q(this,b)};h("pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality",function(b){n.checkImageForCriticality(b)});h("pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkCriticalImages",function(){r(n)});function r(b){b.b={};for(var d=["IMG","INPUT"],a=[],c=0;c<d.length;++c)a=a.concat(l(document.getElementsByTagName(d[c])));if(0!=a.length&&a[0].getBoundingClientRect){for(c=0;d=a[c];++c)q(b,d);a="oh="+b.l;b.f&&(a+="&n="+b.f);if(d=0!=b.a.length)for(a+="&ci="+encodeURIComponent(b.a[0]),c=1;c<b.a.length;++c){var e=","+encodeURIComponent(b.a[c]);131072>=a.length+e.length&&(a+=e)}b.i&&(e="&rd="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(t())),131072>=a.length+e.length&&(a+=e),d=!0);u=a;if(d){c=b.h;b=b.j;var f;if(window.XMLHttpRequest)f=new XMLHttpRequest;else if(window.ActiveXObject)try{f=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")}catch(k){try{f=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}catch(v){}}f&&(f.open("POST",c+(-1==c.indexOf("?")?"?":"&")+"url="+encodeURIComponent(b)),f.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),f.send(a))}}}function t(){var b={},d=document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");if(0==d.length)return{};var a=d[0];if(!("naturalWidth"in a&&"naturalHeight"in a))return{};for(var c=0;a=d[c];++c){var e=a.getAttribute("data-pagespeed-url-hash");e&&(!(e in b)&&0<a.width&&0<a.height&&0<a.naturalWidth&&0<a.naturalHeight||e in b&&a.width>=b[e].o&&a.height>=b[e].m)&&(b[e]={rw:a.width,rh:a.height,ow:a.naturalWidth,oh:a.naturalHeight})}return b}var u="";h("pagespeed.CriticalImages.getBeaconData",function(){return u});h("pagespeed.CriticalImages.Run",function(b,d,a,c,e,f){var k=new p(b,d,a,e,f);n=k;c&&m(function(){window.setTimeout(function(){r(k)},0)})});})();pagespeed.CriticalImages.Run('/mod_pagespeed_beacon','testselenium.com/login','MeUgfxj8kW',false,false,'ycSmdtv-QaE');
//]]></script><img class="login-logo" data-pagespeed-lazy-src="https://n2s-customer-images.s3.amazonaws.com/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b_228_36.png?79" alt="Logo" data-pagespeed-url-hash="1796267855" src="/pagespeed_static/1.JiBnMqyl6S.gif" onload="pagespeed.lazyLoadImages.`enter code here`loadIfVisibleAndMaybeBeacon(this);" onerror="this.onerror=null;pagespeed.lazyLoadImages.loadIfVisibleAndMaybeBeacon(this);"></p>
<div class="login-wrap animated flipInX">
<div class="login-block">
<img data-pagespeed-lazy-src="/images/users/default-user.png" class="img-circle not-logged-avatar" data-pagespeed-url-hash="1346876537" data-pagespeed-lsc-url="testselenium.com/images/users/default-user.png" src="/pagespeed_static/1.JiBnMqyl6S.gif" onload="pagespeed.lazyLoadImages.loadIfVisibleAndMaybeBeacon(this);" onerror="this.onerror=null;pagespeed.lazyLoadImages.loadIfVisibleAndMaybeBeacon(this);">
<form id="login-form" action="/login" method="post"> <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" containerTag="div" containerItemTag="p" id="login-form_es_" style="display:none"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<span style="font-weight:bold">Login failed</span>
<ul><li>dummy</li></ul></div>
<div class="form-group login-input">
<i class="fa fa-envelope overlay"></i>
<input placeholder="Email" class="form-control text-input" name="LoginForm[username]" id="LoginForm_username" type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group login-input">
<i class="fa fa-key overlay"></i>
<input placeholder="Password" class="form-control text-input" name="LoginForm[password]" id="LoginForm_password" type="password"/>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
<div class="text-center"><a href="/forgot-password">Forgot password?</a></div>
</form> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="md-overlay"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" data-pagespeed-no-defer>pagespeed.lazyLoadImages.overrideAttributeFunctions();</script><script>var resizefunc=[];</script>
<script src="/assets/libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/jquery-ui-touch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/jquery-detectmobile/detect.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/jquery-animate-numbers/jquery.animateNumbers.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/ios7-switch/ios7.switch.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/bootstrap-bootbox/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/jquery-sparkline/jquery-sparkline.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/nifty-modal/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/nifty-modal/js/modalEffects.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/sortable/sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/bootstrap.file-input.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/bootstrap-select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/jquery-icheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/prettify/prettify.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/init.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/jquery-notifyjs/notify.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/libs/jquery-notifyjs/styles/metro/notify-metro.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/pages/notifications.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/dismissable_popup.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/trumbowyg.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/bloodhound.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jBeep.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/utility.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/dropdown_selection_ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var timeoutDialog,playBeepCounter=0,explorerAjaxRequest=null;var potentialRecipients=new Bloodhound({datumTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('text'),queryTokenizer:Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,remote:{url:'/recipients?s=%QUERY',wildcard:"%QUERY"}});potentialRecipients.initialize();var afterModalLoaded=function(e){};var showModal=function(url){if($('#myModal').is(':visible')){reloadModal(url);return;}$("#myModal").modal({remote:url});};var reloadModal=function(target){$("#myModal .modal-content").html("<div class=\"modal-header\">Loading...</div>");$.get(target,null,function(data){$("#myModal .modal-content").html(data);});};var createSelectionUi=function(e){new DropDownSelectionUi('#btnAddressBook',{'event':'click','container':'.address_book','dataContainerClass':'.address_book_contents','dataUrl':'/recipients?s=','loadingHtml':"<li>Loading...</li>",'afterDataLoaded':function(){jQuery(document).off('click','.message_to').on('click','.message_to',function(){var parent=$(this).parent();if($(this).is(":checked")){$("#to").tagsinput('add',{"value":$(this).attr("value"),"text":parent.text().trim(),"type":parent.attr("class")});}else{$("#to").tagsinput('remove',{"value":$(this).attr("value"),"text":parent.text().trim(),"type":parent.attr("class")});}});},'dataGenerator':function(obj,reference){if(obj==null)return;if(reference.lookupArray==null){reference.lookupArray=$("#to").val().split(",");}var typeString="",checked="";if(obj.type!="individual"){typeString="&nbsp;("+obj.type.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+obj.type.substr(1)+")";}if($.inArray(obj.value,reference.lookupArray)!=-1){checked=" checked=\"checked\""}return'<li class="'+obj.type+'"><input class="message_to" type="checkbox" value="'+obj.value+'"'+checked+' />&nbsp;'+obj.text+''+typeString+'</li>';},'stateChanger':function(id){var object=jQuery(id+">i");if(object.hasClass('fa-plus')){object.removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');return;}object.removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');}});};var playBeep=function(){if(playBeepCounter<=2){jBeep('/assets/media/notification.wav');playBeepCounter++;return;}}
var closeModal=function(){$("#myModal").modal('hide');};$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({container:'body'});var initTagsInput=function(containerId,potentialRecipients){var el=$(containerId);el.tagsinput({tagClass:function(item){switch(item.type){case'group':return'label label-default';case'individual':return'label label-primary label-important';case'customer':case'storage':case'drive':case'alldrive':return'label label-success';}},itemValue:'value',itemText:'text',typeaheadjs:{name:'recipients',displayKey:'text',source:potentialRecipients.ttAdapter(),templates:{suggestion:function(item){return'<p>'+item.text+' - <strong>'+item.type.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+item.type.substr(1)+'</strong></p>';}}}});el.on('itemRemoved',function(event){});return el;};var initSummerNote=function(containerClass){$(containerClass).trumbowyg({btns:['bold','italic','underline','strikethrough','|','unorderedList','orderedList','|','justifyLeft','justifyCenter','justifyRight','justifyFull']});};var doCompose=function(user,name,email,type){var url='/emails/compose';type=type||"individual";if(user!=null){url+="/"+user;}if(!isNaN(email)&&email!=null){url+="/"+email;}afterModalLoaded=function(e){initSummerNote('.summernote-small');var el=initTagsInput('#to',potentialRecipients);if(name&&type){el.tagsinput('add',{"value":user+":"+type.charAt(0),"text":name,"type":type});}createSelectionUi();};showModal(url);};var doReply=function(user,name,email){doCompose(user,name,email,"individual");};var doReplyCustomer=function(customer,name){doCompose(customer,name,0,"customer");};var doComposeForStorageUsers=function(storage,name){doCompose(storage,name,0,"storage");};var doComposeForDriveUsers=function(drive,name,type){type=type||"drive";doCompose(drive,name,0,type);};(function($){$(document).ready(function(){var dPopup=new DismissablePopup(0),isMyDrivesMenuOpen=false;dPopup.reset();$(document).on('click',".my-drives",function(event){event.preventDefault();if(!isMyDrivesMenuOpen){var siblingUl=$(this).siblings().first();siblingUl.find("li").remove();siblingUl.append("<li><a href=\"#\">Loading <img src=\"/images/arrow-loader.gif\" /></a></li>");$.get('/drive-list',null,function(data){siblingUl.html(data);}).error(function(){siblingUl.html("<li><a href='#'>No drives available</a></li>");});isMyDrivesMenuOpen=true;return false;}isMyDrivesMenuOpen=false;return false;});$(document).on('click','.dropdown-toggle',function(){var span=$(this).find('span').eq(0);if(span&&parseInt(span.html())>0){span.html('');}});$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal','#myModal',function(e){$(e.target).removeData("bs.modal");});$(document).on('show.bs.modal','#myModal',function(e){$(e.target).find(".modal-content").html("<div class=\"modal-header\">Loading...</div>");});$(document).on('click','.btnmodal',function(evt){showModal($(this).attr('href'));evt.preventDefault();return false;});$(document).on('click','.btn-email-compose',function(evt){afterModalLoaded=function(e){initSummerNote('.summernote-small');initTagsInput('#to',potentialRecipients);createSelectionUi();};showModal($(this).attr('href'));evt.preventDefault();return false;});$(document).on('submit','#emailComposeForm',function(evt){$("#btn-send").attr("disabled","disabled").html('<i class="icon-paper-plane-1 fa-spin"></i> Sending...');$.post('/emails/compose',$(this).serialize(),function(response){if(response.status==true){$('#emailComposeForm')[0].reset();$('#to').tagsinput('removeAll');closeModal();swal("Sent!",response.reason==''?"Message Sent!":response.reason,response.reason==''?'success':'warning');return;}swal("Sorry!","Failed to send message to recipient(s), please try again later!","error");}).fail(function(){swal("Sorry!","Failed to send message to recipient(s), please try again later!","error");}).always(function(){$("#btn-send").removeAttr("disabled").html('<i class="icon-paper-plane-1"></i> Send');});evt.preventDefault();return false;});$(document).on('shown.bs.tooltip',function(e){setTimeout(function(){$(e.target).tooltip('hide');},3000);});$(document).on('loaded.bs.modal','#myModal',function(e){afterModalLoaded(e);afterModalLoaded=function(){};});$(document).on('click',"[class^='drives driveexplore']",function(evt){var driveClass=$(this).attr("class").replace('subdrop','').trim().split("_"),that=this,iconElement=$(this).find("i:first"),oldClass=iconElement.attr("class"),oldContent=iconElement.html();iconElement.removeClass(oldClass).html('<img width="20px" src="/images/circle-loader.gif" />');blockUI(null,"Please wait..");if(explorerAjaxRequest!=null){explorerAjaxRequest.abort();}explorerAjaxRequest=$.ajax({type:'POST',url:'/drive-alive',data:{id:driveClass[1]},success:function(data){switch(data){case"ok":var href=$(that).attr("href");if(""==href){break;}window.document.location=href;return;case"dead_server":autohidenotify('warning',"top center",'Storage Server for this drive is currently offline.','');break;case"maintenance_mode":autohidenotify('warning',"top center",'Drive is in maintenance mode.','');$(that).remove();break;default:autohidenotify('warning',"top center",'Selected drive does not exist.','');$(that).remove();break;}unblockUI();},error:function(){unblockUI();autohidenotify('warning',"top center",'Storage Server for this drive is currently offline.','');},complete:function(){iconElement.html(oldContent).addClass(oldClass);}});evt.preventDefault();return false;});});$(window).ready(function(){});})(jQuery);</script>
<a id="back-to-top" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg back-to-top" role="button" title="Click to return on the top page"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
    public void VerifyUserNamePassFieldPresence() {             
        assertElementPresent("//input[@name='name-of-this-field' and @type='text']");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LoginForm_username']")).getText();
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LoginForm_username']")));
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LoginForm_password']")).getText().matches("Password"));
    }
```

Error:

```
    FAILED: VerifyUserNamePassFieldPresence
    java.lang.AssertionError: expected [true] but found [false]
        at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
        at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:512)
        at org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
        at org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:51)
        at pages.LoginPage.VerifyUserNamePassFieldPresence(LoginPage.java:36)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
```

Comment: Can you share proper HTML you are trying to test?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have added the HTML as well.

Comment: @AvinashPandey Can you consider to make separate code blocks for the HTML DOM, your Code & Error Stack Trace in the Question area for SO volunteers to analyze your Question properly? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling

> Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LoginForm_password']")).getText().matches("Password"));

You should first store the text value of your xPath in a String variable followed by Assert.assertEquals. In your case your code block will look like

> String getPasswordText =
>   driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LoginForm_password']")).getText();
>
> Assert.assertEquals(getPasswordText,"Password");

By dividing your code you would easily debug it and see whether getPasswordText has the desired expected text value or not.

Hope that helps !

Comment: if `id` is available, then why are you using `xpath` locator? and any reason for down voting my answer?

Comment: Sorry brother I dint know that giving a new reply would down vote your response. I specifically did not down voted it. 

Further, in response to your query I simply suggested the same way which Avinash was doing. He was using Xpath and fetching the id attribute so in order to debug it more properly I suggested to store it in a string variable first to find out whether value is being returned or not.

Again, I dint down voted your response. Sorry for the confusion !

Comment: @Test(priority = 3)
 public void VerifyUserNamePassFieldPresence() {

  String getUsernameText = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LoginForm_username']")).getText().toString();
  System.out.println(getUsernameText);
  Assert.assertEquals(getUsernameText,"Email");
  String getPasswordText = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LoginForm_password']")).getText();
  System.out.println(getPasswordText);
  Assert.assertEquals(getPasswordText,"Password");

Comment: Still getting an error -FAILED: VerifyUserNamePassFieldPresence
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Password] but found []

Comment: Did first assertion passed which is  Assert.assertEquals(getUsernameText,"Email");

Comment: Try below xpath while fetching getUserNameText
String getUsernameText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='LoginForm_username']"​)).getText();

Comment: Gives an error invalid character, delete this token - String getUsernameText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='LoginForm_username‌​']"​)).getText();        java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Password] but found []

Comment: Can you share your app url so that I can create a working locator at my end and share it with you.
Possible ?

Comment: Can i message you ? find there is no way to message you.

Comment: Thanks, I have sent you the url on the above e-mail. Thanks again